# How do you delete a database in (LocalDb)\v11.0 MVC 4?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-4

I have a similar problem to this guy http://forums.asp.net/t/1849215.aspx/1?Ef+5+woes+Could+not+drop+constraint+

I deleted a table using database explorer of VS2012 express and seems like it was a bad idea because now when i triy to do migrations i get this error:

```
'FK_dbo.PriceGuides_dbo.Animals_AnimalId' is not a constraint.
Could not drop constraint. See previous errors.
```

This is false, i get this error even when i have deleted or removed anything that is called Priceguides the model class of priceguides & the table of priceguides.

Comment: You ask in your title how to delete a database but the body of your question actually asks how to drop a table…? Which one is it?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are using automatic migrations right?  Can you post the migration that it's trying to run?  It sounds like it's trying to drop a constraint that's not there.

Here is an answer I gave someone else that got into a similar predicament:

[SQL Azure table not created with EF Migrations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13826651/sql-azure-table-not-created-with-ef-migrations/13972292#13972292)

Reading that might get you back on the right track.  Also you can specifically try this;
EF doesn't just look at your models and your DB scheme.  It keeps track of all the migrations that have ever been run in the __MigrationHistory table.  Look in this table and see if there is still a reference to the old migration that did create the 'FK_dbo.PriceGuides_dbo.Animals_AnimalId' constraint.  Automatic migrations will probably continue to try and roll it back as long as there is a record of it being created in the __MigrationHistory table.

If you have updated your models and your DBcontext